# tcpdump with multiple subtypes specified?

Tags: shell-script, wifi, osx, tcpdump

I'm trying to create a bash script to detect deauthentication attacks (I am on Mac). Whilst I am aware that the command:

```
$ tcpdump -l -I -i en0 -e -s 256 type mgt subtype deauth
```

will detect deauthentication packets, I would also like to simultaneously detect disassociation packets.  Normally, you would detect disassociation packets with:

```
$ tcpdump -l -I -i en0 -e -s 256 type mgt subtype disassoc
```

However, I was wondering if there was some way to manipulate this command to scan for both disassociation and deauthentication packets at the same time? E.g. the command:

```
$ tcpdump -l -I -i en0 -e -s 256 type mgt subtype deauth disassoc
```

will obviously not work but I hope that helps you get an idea of what I'm asking.

Furthermore, I completely understand that simply using the command:

```
$ tcpdump -l -I -i en0 -e -s 256 type mgt
```

will show me all management frames including both disassociation and deauthentication packets but will get clogged with other irrelevant frames like beacons, probe requests etc.

Indeed, I am aware that a simple `grep` implementation for example could remove pretty much all unwanted packets and leave just disassociation and deauthentication packets but I feel that this is a rather bodged way of doing it and would require more, inefficient, bash computational time to try and parse each line of every single management frame flying through the air.

Is there a simple way to modify the above `tcpdump` command to have it detect the two packet types I want? Or is it the case that I will have to look for a different sort of solution like with `grep` as I mentioned above?

P.S. I am on OSX rather than Linux.

Comment: The question has its merits, but too long. Could you shorten it up a bit?

Comment: I have no way to test this, but try `type mgt subtype disassoc or type mgt subtype deauth`. You may need parens and a quoted string: `'(type mgt subtype disassoc) or (type mgt subtype deauth)'`

Comment: @MarkPlotnick Thanks for your reply! I appreciate you trying to help me out but I've been told that using `tcpdump -l -I -i en0 -e -s 256 'type mgt and (subtype deauth or subtype disassoc)'` works perfectly for what I need.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As described in the [tcpdump manpage](https://man.openbsd.org/tcpdump.8), you can combine filters wth keywords `and` , `or`, and `not`. You can use parentheses for grouping (note that to have your shell parse the command line correctly, you'll likely need quotes):

```
 tcpdump -l -I -i en0 -e -s 256 'type mgt and (subtype deauth or subtype disassoc)'
```

Comment: Perfect, this is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you so much

Comment: Quick question: what difference would using `and` make as opposed to using `or` or `not` if any?

Comment: I'm unsure of what you mean. 'A and B' means that both conditions A and B must be statisfied while 'A or B' means that it's sufficient that only either A or B is satisfied for the filter to match. Using one or the other depends on the filter you need.

Comment: Ah, I see. I just wanted to clarify. I think that using `or` satisfies my use case as I am looking for both disassociation and deauthentication packets at the same time.

Comment: Yes, that's the correct filter in your case. Note that a filter 'subtype deauth and subtype disassoc' would not work anyway since the same packet cannot simultaneously be of subtype deassoc and deauth. The filter expression is applied on each packet individually.