# tcpdump to perform wireless capture with advanced filters

Tags: wifi, macos, tcpdump, wireshark

I’m trying to use tcpdump to perform realtime wireless captures (without the option to save the file) on a MAC. My wireless interface is en0. I want to use similar filters as I would in Wireshark. My exact goal is to capture channel utilization and client count, but filter on a condition (great than or less than). The way I would do this in Wireshark is with the following filters:

```
Channel utilization:

wlan.bssid == 11:22:33:44:55:66 && wlan.qbss.cu > 50

Client count:

wlan.bssid == 11:22:33:44:55:66 && wlan.qbss.scount == 7
```

How can I do the same with tcpdump?

The closest I found so far was another post [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/461786/tcpdump-with-multiple-subtypes-specified).

Note: Using tshark is not an option as I want to use this in a script and it needs to be exportable to systems that don't have Wirehshark installed.

Comment: `tcpdump` uses the pcap filter language. If I understand the [manual page](https://www.tcpdump.org/manpages/pcap-filter.7.html) right, it can't filter on BSSID symbolically, but if you know the position of the data in the packet, you can use array index notation. This is explained in the *expr relop expr* paragraph.

Comment: By the way, according to [documentation](https://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureFilters), Wireshark uses the same pcap-filter language for *capture* filters. I guess that `wlan.bssid` is a *display* filter. The difference between the two is clarified on the referenced documentation page.

Comment: You're absolutely right. I always confuse the display filter with the capture filter. You've given me the idea to dump out the beacons (type mgt subtype beacon) to an ascii file and then parse it for the details that I need.